# How can I do auto-forwarding for azure service bus in python?

Tags: python, azure, azureservicebus, azure-sdk-python

I found that in C# Azure SDK we are able to use `SubscriptionDescription` class to set the `ForwardTo` property to achieve auto-forwarding.

However when I check for python SDK, the `Subscription` class is said to be the same as `SubscriptionDescription` class in C# however they do not have the same property as the `Subscription` class for python SDK is missing out `ForwardTo` property.

Is it unable to achieve by using python or there is other workaround for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**`SBSubscription`** is the class which you are looking for.This will be available in `**azure-mgmt-servicebus**`. you can find the complete implementation in below repo:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/8e8d5ab93c5c37e48adac04fc3825ddae88b9210/sdk/servicebus/azure-mgmt-servicebus/azure/mgmt/servicebus/models/sb_subscription_py3.py

Hope it helps.

Comment: There is mentioning in that file which `Variables are only populated by the server, and will be ignored when sending a request.` tho.

Comment: You need to create first a azure.mgmt.servicebus.ServiceBusManagementClient. This page, even if not specific to SB, will explain how to do that with credentials https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/python/python-sdk-azure-authenticate?view=azure-python

Comment: @LaurentMazuel I see, ok I will try it!